# pecl-ssh2-0.11 Freebsd Compile error after upgrading to php 5.3.2

Tags: php, ssh, freebsd, port, pecl

Hi I've been looking for answers for this all day and can find nothing to solve my issue.

I also came across a question about this port on serverfault that I just answered and will hopefully help someone else.

however my problem is this.

While running "make" in /usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2

I get this error

```
===>  Building for pecl-ssh2-0.11
/bin/sh /usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/include -I/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/main -I/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11 -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include  -I/usr/local/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing   -c /usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c -o ssh2.lo
 cc -I. -I/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11 -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/include -I/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/main -I/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11 -I/usr/local/include/php -I/usr/local/include/php/main -I/usr/local/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/local/include/php/Zend -I/usr/local/include/php/ext -I/usr/local/include/php/ext/date/lib -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -O2 -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -c /usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/ssh2.o
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c: In function 'zif_ssh2_methods_negotiated':
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:502: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_string_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:503: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_string_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:507: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_string_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:508: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_string_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:509: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_string_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:510: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_string_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:515: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_string_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:516: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_string_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:517: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_string_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:518: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_string_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c: In function 'zif_ssh2_poll':
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:891: error: 'zval' has no member named 'is_ref'
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:891: error: 'zval' has no member named 'refcount'
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:901: error: 'zval' has no member named 'is_ref'
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:902: error: 'zval' has no member named 'refcount'
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c: In function 'zif_ssh2_publickey_add':
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:1011: error: 'zval' has no member named 'is_ref'
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:1012: error: 'zval' has no member named 'refcount'
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:1044: warning: passing argument 1 of '_efree' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c: In function 'zif_ssh2_publickey_list':
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:1103: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_stringl_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
/usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11/ssh2.c:1104: warning: passing argument 4 of 'add_assoc_stringl_ex' discards qualifiers from pointer target type
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2/work/ssh2-0.11.
*** Error code 1

Stop in /usr/ports/security/pecl-ssh2.
```

I am trying to recompile this port after upgrading from php 5.2.12 to php 5.3.2 which was released on freebsd over the weekend.

I have run out of ideas and steam with this so if anyone has any ideas on what this might be  I would be truly grateful.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://serverfault.com/questions/91347/pecl-install-ssh2-make-failed

Comment: this is not a dupe with that bug I answered that bug it is slightly different to this error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pecl-ssh doesn't work on PHP 5.3, per this:

http:/pecl.php.net/bugs/bug.php?id=16727

My recommendation: install [phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: umm I saw that bug and people say it works after applying the patch which I have done this is a slightly different error message to the one I am seeing as I have applied that patch. Unless I am missing something that bug does not state the pecl-ssh2 will not work with php 5.3.2

Comment: You're right - pecl-ssh2 does work after you apply the patch.  But the fact remains that a patch *must* be applied none-the-less.  Neither the latest SVN or the latest release version include the patch.  Note how the bug report is still open.  What would you propose?  That the bug report ought to be closed, even if the patch isn't committed, simply because the patch exists?  Awesome!


There are other issues, regardless, as elaborated here:


http://drupal.org/node/671702#comment-2629172

Comment: I understand that patch is needed to build pecl-ssh2 howerver that is not what I have posted. The error in my question has nothing to do with the "static" in the code I have applied that patch and still I cannot build the package via the freebsd ports system.

Comment: Hence my recommendation. Even if you do succeed in getting it compiled you're still going to run into problems as the drupal.org link elaborates upon.

Comment: Ok I see your point and to be honest I haven't yet got around to testing the package even though it is installed. Will test it today but definitely sounds like we might have to rewrite some of that code.
Ill let you know what our decision is.

Comment: we tested the code in our application and it appears to be working fine so we are going to stick with it for now. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

So no sure if the problem is with the pecl-ssh2 package or FreeBSD ports as I managed to install the package via pecl install.

These are the instructions I followed

http://bugssite.org/blog/2009/08/02/php-5-3-0-ssh-2-0-11-how-to-get-it-working/2/

So it does seam to work for php 5.3.2 however I cannot make it using FreeBSD ports system